# Do applications developed with Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS need to assign nulls when instances are not used anymore?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am using `Xamarin.Android` after having used `Xamarin.iOS` for quite some time now.

One thing I noticed in Xamarin samples is the need to set fields to `null` after there are disposed or closed.

Here is a sample for a `Xamarin.Android` application showcasing the use of the  [camera2](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/android5.0/Camera2Basic/Camera2Basic/Camera2BasicFragment.cs) API. Here's what is done when the background thread is stopped:

```
private void StopBackgroundThread()
{
    mBackgroundThread.QuitSafely();

    try
    {
        mBackgroundThread.Join();
        mBackgroundThread = null;
        mBackgroundHandler = null;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.PrintStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is something that I learned was not needed in .NET framework; the JIT knows when an object is not referenced anymore without me hinting at it.

**Question**

Do applications developed with `Xamarin.iOS` and `Xamarin.Android` *really* need developers to set values to `null` when instances are not being used anymore?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Knowing that calling Dispose several times can't be a problem, why not just do something like clickButton?.Dispose() and avoid setting the instance to null?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto In this example I have in the question, this is code auto generated by Xamarin.iOS...

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have updated the sample to avoid the dispose pattern which is an issue on its own.

Comment: I've upvoted in hope for better visibility. Unfortunately my knowledge is limited to that of the .NET where we agree that the `= null;` is not needed

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks!